# empty() not working in PHP

Tags: php

I am working with PHP 5.4 and I am submitting a form via POST request, and I want to check to see if one of the values is null, or populated. However the condition does not appear to resolving to true and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
        $route = $_POST['route']; 
        echo ("route: " . $route);//this is displaying 'route:null'


        if(empty($route))
        {
            echo ("route2: " . $route);                 
        }
```

I have also tried to use `isset` `is_null` and `$route === null` `$route == null`

None seem to work .

I have also tried inserting `true` into the `if` statement to make sure that true is resolving correctly, but it does.

Comment: Is it displaying "route: null" or "route: "?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic it is displaying `route:null`

Comment: Well then, you are probably receiving "null" as a string, because ou are submitting your form via ajax, and js is parsing the field as null. First, do `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get.

Comment: @Blaine `null` is a special boolean type in PHP. The string `"null"` is just that, a string with those characters in it. `empty()` checks for the boolean `null` value (not string).

Comment: @D.Kasipovic `print_r` is: ` [route] => null `

Comment: My bad, use `var_dump($_POST)`, it should clarify the issue at hand.

Comment: You were right about it being a string.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic if you want to add an answer, I'll accept. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wrote a little explanation as an answer. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `echo` is displaying `null` then it is not null. It is a string "null" which are two entirely different things.

This, in fact is a common problem when using javascript to post to php. Javascript's null gets converted to string when posting to php, thus passing all checks (`empty()`, `isset()`, ...).

The easiest way to see these issues is to do a `var_dump($_POST)`, which will give you exactly what you have received in your post.

In your case you are receiving string "null", which in no way can pass the `empty()` check. You either need to check if `$route=="null"` or fix your javascript so it does not send null values.

Fixing javascript is the proper way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The POST variable does not contain anything. Either it does not exist on the form or you have it misspelled.

According to the docs null is empty.

https://www.php.net/empty

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
> Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Comment: Actually the POST variable does contain something. A string with the value `null`.

Comment: @Blaine then it is not empty and is working correctly. Try $route == 'null'. That should work. Need the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Empty - Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

How about try using (or adding):

```
if(is_null($route))
```

or

```
if(!isset($route))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($_POST['route']) && !empty($_POST['route']) ) {
  $route = $_POST['route'];
  echo "Route: $route";
} else {
  echo "Route: None specified";
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `isset` with `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `$_POST` is returning `null` as a string I had to do this:

```
        $route = $_POST['route']; 
        echo ("route: " . $route);


        if($route == 'null')//surround null in quotes
        {
            echo ("route2: " . $route);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This ;)**

```
function convert_null($data)
        {
        $data = str_replace(null,"",$data);     
        $data = str_replace("null","",$data);
        $data = trim($data);
        return $data; 
        };
        
        
    convert_null($route);
    
    if(empty($route))
                {
                    echo ("route2: " . $route);                 
                };
```